Authenticate to Azure Devops Python API using Managed identity
I have currently been authenticating to Azure Devops Python API via personal access tokens, but we are now asked to move to using user-assigned managed identities. How can I use an MSI to authenticate, both with and without the Python wrapper?


How can I use an MSI to authenticate, both with and without the Python wrapper?

Based on your description, you need to use User Managed identity to authenticate Azure DevOps Rest API. You can refer to the following steps:
Step1: Add the User Managed Identity to Azure DevOps Organization(Organization Settings -> Users). You can directly search the User MSI and add it. We need to make sure that the Organization and MSI are in the same tenant. Then you can grant the required permissions to the MSI in Azure DevOps Organization.
Refer to this doc: Add managed identity to Organization
Stpe2: We can install the azure-identity python package to get the Managed Identity Token.
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="MSIclientID")
token = credential.get_token('499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default').token

We can find the MSI client id in Azure Portal.
For example:

Note:  You need to set 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default when getting the token. This is used to authenticate Azure DevOps.
Step3: You can use the token to authenticate Rest API.
Here is an example:
import requests
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="MSIclientID")
token = credential.get_token("499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default").token


headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

organization = "your_organization"
project = "your_project"
url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.json())

Update:
I can reproduce the managed identity is unavailable error when I running the py script on my local machine.

The cause of the issue is that Managed identities are only available within Azure environments. If you are running the code locally or in an environment that does not support managed identities, you will encounter this error.
To solve this issue, you can create an Azure VM and add User MSI to the Azure VM.
For example: Navigate to Security -> Identity -> User Managed

Then you need to log in to the Azure VM and run the Python script to use the User MSI authentication.
Here is my sample:
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicTokenAuthentication

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="MSIclientID")

token = credential.get_token("499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default")


credentials = BasicTokenAuthentication({"access_token": token.token})
connection = Connection(base_url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}", creds=credentials)


client = connection.clients.get_git_client()
repos = client.get_repositories(project="projectname")
for repo in repos:
    print(repo.name)


Hey thanks for this. But how will this work in case I want to use the Python wrapper instead of the REST API directly? My code below throws an exception that the managed identity is unavailable even though it is added to the repo.
`credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="xxx")
credentials = BasicTokenAuthentication(credential.get_token("499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default").token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)`

@anjalib I can reproduce the same issue when using the python sample code. The cause of the issue is that Managed identities are only available within Azure environments. If you are running the code locally or in an environment that does not support managed identities, you will encounter this error. Refer to my update. You need to create an azure resource and add User MSI to the azure resource. Then you need to run the python script on the azure resource to let it work.

Hey - so I continue to face issues even now. I posted about this in the Microsoft stackoverflow too but couldnt get any help. This script is supposed to run during a build in ADO, which runs in a different tenant from where the MSI is. The MSI is granted permission to the repo, however, so I'm not sure what else I should be doing

@anjalib how do you grant the permissions to the repo? You need to make sure that the MSI and the repo are in the same tenant. In this case, you can add the MSI to your org and grant permissions. And you need to create a self hosted agent based on an azure VM which uses the MSI. Then it can work

If the MSI and Repo are not in the same tenant, you are not able to use MSI to access azure Devops.
